# REGEX - Finding an specific XML tag and removing between between specific points

Tags: python, regex, xml

My xml looks like the following :

```xml
<example>
<Test_example>Author%5773637864827/Testing-75873874hdueu47.jpg</Test_example>
<Test_example>Auth0r%5773637864827/Testing245-75873874hdu6543u47.ts</Test_example>
```

This XML has 100 lines and i am interested in the tag "`<Test_example>`". In this tag I want to remove everything until it sees a `/` and when it sees a `-` remove everything until it sees the full stop.

End result should be

```xml
<Test_example>Testing.jpg</Test_example>
<Test_example>Testing245.ts</Test_example>
```

I am a beginner and would love some help on this. I think maybe regex is the best method?

Comment: Need to mention i am only interested in locating the tag <Test_example> wherever it is mentioned in the XML

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I parse XML in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912434/how-do-i-parse-xml-in-python)

Comment: the python attempted is not good enough so i haven't added it. the .jpg and .ts needs to be retained . I ma just looking at how i can find a specific tag and remove everything till it sees a '/' and removes everything which starts with a ' -' till it sees a full stop.

Answer (score 1):

Consider [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/all/), the special-purpose language designed to to transform XML files, using its `substring-before` and `substring-after` functions. Python's third-party module, [`lxml`](https://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html), can run XSLT 1.0 scripts. And because XSLT is portable, it can be run in other [languages or executables](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt/info) beyond Python:

**XSLT** *(save as .xsl file, a special .xml file)*

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Test_example">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-before(substring-after(., '/'), '-'), 
                                   '.',
                                   substring-after(., '.'))"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Python**

```
import lxml.etree as et

xml = et.parse('Input.xml')
xsl = et.parse('Script.xsl')

transformer = et.XSLT(xsl)
new_xml = transformer(xml)

# PRINT TO CONSOLE
print(new_xml)

# SAVE TO FILE
with open('Output.xml', 'wb') as f:
   f.write(new_xml)
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<example>
   <Test_example>Testing.jpg</Test_example>
   <Test_example>Testing245.ts</Test_example>
</example>
```

## <kbd>[Python Demo](https://rextester.com/LXIHVI64916)</kbd>

## <kbd>[XSLT Demo](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/93dFepC)</kbd>